# Why is a class not being reckognized even though it is in the same package of the one I'm running?

Tags: java, class, package

I have two classes in the same "test" directory.

```
package test;
public class Human {
    String name;
    public Human(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println(name + ": hello!");
    }
}
```

and

```
package test;
//import test.Human <- have tried this
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human bia = new Human("bia");
        //test.Human bia = new test.Human("bia"); <- have tried this
        bia.speak();
    }
}
```

When I try to run it with `java Hello.java`, it gives me

```
Hello.java:4: error: cannot find symbol

 Human bia = new Human("bia");

 ^   symbol:   class Human   

 location: class Hello
```

I also tried to run all the other versions with `java test.Hello.java` but it also doesnt work, giving me

> Error: Could not find or load main class test.Hello.java
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Hello.java

[Picture of my IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zovVz.png)

Also, I just found that it compiles and runs on Eclipse, but not on VS Code.

Comment: This might sound dumb but did you try restarting your IDE? Sometimes the IDE have delay in recognizing the new class you created.

Comment: `java test/Hello.java`

Comment: @YUNGFOOKYONG I just did it and it didn't solve it

Comment: @JonasOliveiraPereira Well on my side, I recreated a package and added both of your files inside, and it is able to run with no error, can you add a screenshot of your IDE and your package?

Comment: @knittl I am in test directory when I try to run it. Just tried this command inside it and it gives me "Error: Could not find or load main class test.Hello.java  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Hello.java". 
I tried also in the parent directory and it gave the same error I showed in the question

Comment: @YUNGFOOKYONG I just included a picture of my IDE at the bottom of my question

Comment: @JonasOliveiraPereira I strongly believe that this is caused by your compiler, try restarting PC or simply try it again later.

Comment: @YUNGFOOKYONG I just installed Eclipse and ran on it and it worked. Don't know why but I guess I'll have to use Eclipse for java by now. Thanks :)